# AWS S3 file overwrite not working with crontab

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a script which downloads a file from my S3 bucket, overwriting the existing file.  The intention is to run the script once a day so that the file is constantly overwritten and updated.

Here's the command, on crontab:

```
03 23 * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/aws s3 cp s3://sfbucket.bucket/sf_events.json /Users/Documents/TownSounds_Javascript/data/sf_events.json >> /Users/Documents/logs3.txt 2>&1
```

Really, I only need it to run once every day.  However, the script is failing to replace the existing file - it's not overwriting it.  The only way I can get it to overwrite the file is if I change the crontab to: `* * * * *`

The output logs appear normal, and appears as if the command is being executed normally.

My question is: why would the command not work with this:

```
03 23 * * *
```

But `* * * * *` works - (only once, the file is replaced, but then fails to be updated still).

Answer (score 1):

If the `cron` job is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, please note that the **instances use `UTC` as their timezone**.

So, the crontab is probably working, but you haven't waited until the time that it has actually run. If you leave it alone for 24 hours, you'll probably discover that it did work, but it would have run at 11pm UTC rather than 11pm in your personal timezone.

To fix this, **translate your local time into UTC**. (There are online tools to assist with this.)

Comment: John - thanks, but I don't think this is actually the issue.  I left it for days on end and nothing ran.

Comment: Rather, it did run, but it didn't overwrite the file!

Comment: Didn't overwrite _which_ file? The file in the S3 bucket, or the `/Users/Documents/logs3.txt` log file?

Comment: the file in the s3 bucket.

Comment: In that case, it would appear that the cron job did not run. Is there anything in the `logs3.txt` file that indicates the job ran?